# Facebook Graph API returns different Place name based on query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When using the Facebook Graph API Explorer:

Requesting an Event with this:

```
/808892439234256?fields=place{name}
```

Returns this:

```
{
  "place": {
    "name": "Cleveland",
    "id": "105653772801120"
  },
  "id": "808892439234256"
}
```

But requesting the Place (of the Event) with this:

```
/105653772801120?fields=name
```

Returns this:

```
{
  "name": "Ohio City, Cleveland",
  "id": "105653772801120"
}
```

Why are the Place names different?  Is there a way to return the complete place name in the event instead of having to query the Place, without using FQL?

Comment: check on  graph api explorer both are different events not same event

Comment: They are not both Events.  The first id is for an Event object, and the second id is for a Place object.